# Missing Dependencies for jersey project

Tags: java, web-services, maven, tomcat, jersey

I'm using maven. Newest versions of all jersey jars and I can not post to my service running on tomcat... has anyone faces this issue? Been at it for hours.

> SEVERE: Missing dependency for method public java.lang.String      restService.status.SubmitName.post(java.io.InputStream) at parameter at index 0
>
> SEVERE: Method, public java.lang.String restService.status.SubmitName.post(java.io.InputStream), annotated with POST of resource class restService.status.SubmitName, is not recognized as valid resource method.

Here are my dependencies:

```
<dependencies>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.jvnet</groupId>
    <artifactId>mimepull</artifactId>
    <version>1.6</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-multipart</artifactId>
    <version>1.18</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-servlet</artifactId>
    <version>1.18</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
    <version>1.18</version>
  </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Comment: This is about a Jersey application-layer dependency, not a missing-library dependency.

Comment: This was happening before I've been using maven also. What do you mean by that just started using maven yesterday..

Comment: This isn't a Maven dependency, this is an issue of not having your application wired correctly.

Comment: Wish I could accept this as an answer! you saved my entire project. I went in an rewired some stuff following the jersey documentation and it works great now. I would have never have thought it was my code. Thanks.